# Spring mvc: How can I set timezone per user?

Tags: spring-mvc, timezone

I have data in database stored in UTC.

Every user has timezone in his setting. How can I handle timezone conversion during display and save?

Answer (score 0):

Spring does not have built-in support for this like they do for locales. There is a [ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-1528) requesting this functionality but it has been been around since 2005.

If you are using JSP, you can use the [fmt:timeZone](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/timeZone.html) tag to set the timezone to be used on any nested fmt:formatDate tags.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it help to have a converter / PropertyEditor for your Date objects that does exactly that (applies the user timezone when converting to String for displaying and the UTC timezone when converting back to a Date for processing) ?